# Wordpress - How to pass data to shortcode via form

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have custom post type called "forms", and has a **sub-menu page** which contains **form**, to add a **name**.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'form_builder_add');

function form_builder_add() {

  //create new top-level menu
  add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=forms', 'Add name', 'Add name', 'manage_options', 'form-dashboards', 'add_names');

}

function add_names() {
    echo 
    '
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    ';
}
```

and I have **shortcode** and **foocode** where I want to spit out the values from the form.

```
add_shortcode( 'foocode', 'prefix_foocode' );

function prefix_foocode() {

    return 'This is  '. $_POST['name'] . ' testing';
}
```

So when I call the shortcode from the post, it should have the value of **name** from the form.

[foocode]

This is **example name** testing.

Comment: This is a very unrealistic way to do this. The ```$_POST``` variable will be present only when if you make some **post** request to a page. So, the page you place your shortcode, you have to make **post** request to that page to gain ```$_POST``` variable. Being that said, your form action should be pointing that page like so ```<form method="post" action="/my-page-with-shortcode">``` than the shortcode function can access ```$_POST``` variable.

Comment: The shortcode function and the form are on the same page, hence why action=""